# docker-compose: run a command on a pgsql container

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am trying to run the following `docker-compose` file:

```
version: "3"
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    container_name: pgsql
    environment:
      - foo=foo
      - bar=bar
    volumes:
      - ./sql/:/opt/sql
    command: bash /opt/sql/create-db.sql
#    command: ps -aux
  web:
    image: benit/debian-web
    container_name: web
    depends_on:
      - db
    ports:
      - 80:80
    volumes:
      - ./html:/var/www/html
```

I am encountering an error with the line:

```
command: bash /opt/sql/create-db.sql
```

It is because pgsql service is not started.  It can be monitored with `command: ps -aux`

How can I run my script once pgsql service is started ?

Comment: have you tried running `/etc/init.d/postgresql start &&` command just before the db create command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a volume to provide an initialization sql script:

```
version: "3"
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    container_name: pgsql
    environment:
      - foo=foo
      - bar=bar
    volumes:
      - ./sql/:/opt/sql
      - ./init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql
  web:
    image: benit/debian-web
    container_name: web
    depends_on:
      - db
    ports:
      - 80:80
    volumes:
      - ./html:/var/www/html
```

This will work because original Posgresql dockerfile contains a script (that runs after Posrgres has been started) which will execute any `*.sql` files from `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/` folder.

By mounting your local volume in that place, your sql files will be run at the right time.

It's actually mentioned in documentation for that image: https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres under the `How to extend this image` section.

Comment: that's working! I don't understand why. Could you explain the magic with `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/`?Is that a docker tips?