# How to execute properly a bash script after Docker compose container starts

Tags: bash, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, psql

###### Problem Description

My goal is to execute a bash script **after** the **docker compose** container of *PostgreSQL* has started correctly. My Script does more or less the following:

1. **Downloads** tables definitions from remote Redshift Cluster to a **local** .csv
2. I run **local queries** in PostgreSQL to recreate the tables/users, etc.

###### Script

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

tables=(
  'schema1.table1'
  'schema2.table2'
)

users=(
  'user1'
  'user2'
)

# Create a .pgpass file
echo "$QA_REDSHIFT_HOST:$QA_REDSHIFT_PORT:$QA_REDSHIFT_DB_NAME:$QA_REDSHIFT_USER:$QA_REDSHIFT_DB_PASSWORD" >~/.pgpass
echo "localhost:5432:$POSTGRES_DB:$POSTGRES_USER:$POSTGRES_PASSWORD" >>~/.pgpass
chmod 600 ~/.pgpass

# 1. Download database table definitions
printf -v pg_dump_tables -- '-t %s ' "${tables[@]}"
pg_dump $pg_dump_tables --schema-only -h "$QA_REDSHIFT_HOST" -p "$QA_REDSHIFT_PORT" -U "$QA_REDSHIFT_USER" "$QA_REDSHIFT_DB_NAME" >schemas.sql

# 2. Create users in the local database
for user in "${users[@]}"; do
  psql -h localhost -d "$POSTGRES_DB" -U "$POSTGRES_USER" -c "CREATE USER $user"
done
```

###### Docker

My PostgreSQL container looks like:

```yaml
  redshift:
    image: postgres:11
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: ${POSTGRES_DB}
      POSTGRES_USER: ${POSTGRES_USER}
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
      QA_REDSHIFT_HOST: ${QA_REDSHIFT_HOST}
      QA_REDSHIFT_PORT: ${QA_REDSHIFT_PORT:-5439}
      QA_REDSHIFT_USER: ${QA_REDSHIFT_USER:-root}
      QA_REDSHIFT_DB_NAME: ${QA_REDSHIFT_DB_NAME:-test}
      QA_REDSHIFT_DB_PASSWORD: ${QA_REDSHIFT_DB_PASSWORD}
    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready -d test" ]
      interval: 5s
      retries: 5
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - ./scripts/redshift/mock_db.sh:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/mock_db.sh
```

###### Errors

I tried to use a [volume to provide an initialization sql script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54183439/18466829), but throws me a permission error:

```sh
/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/mock_db.sh: line 49: schemas.sql: Permission denied
```

It also seems that it **can't connect properly** to the local PostgreSQL database. My guess is that it is getting executed before the proper database initialization. This other error:

```sh
+ psql -h localhost -d test -U root -c 'CREATE USER user1'
psql: connection to server at "localhost" (127.0.0.1), port 5432 failed: Connection refused
Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
```

*Note: When I run this exact command manually when I am attached to the container, it works.*

###### Question

Running this script **manually** in the container **works** without any problem. But when I try to run it automatically when I do `docker-compose up` it **fails**.

What is the proper way of running this script after `redshift` **service** has **started** correctly?